# How to pass html as parameter to a Batch-programm?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

### My goal / problem

The following batch program can be used to display my problem:

```
echo first param: %1 third param: %3
echo '%2'
```

my goal is to get the following output for param2 (I am aware that it would be a little easier as last parameter but that's not what is needed):

> ```
> '<body><p style="font-familiy:Arial,Cascadia">MyText</p></body>'
> ```

My question is how to call it correctly or change the cmd-code so that the 2nd parameter is not interpreted as multiple parameters

### First try: backslashes as escape character

if I escape the double quotes with a backslash like so:

```
demo p1 "<body><p style=\"font-family:Arial,Cascadia\">MyText</p></body>" p3
```

the output for param2 is

> ''"<p style="font-family:Arial'

and the rest of the HTML code is in param3.

### Second try: double double quotes as escape character

My second attempt was to escape with double dobule quotes:

```
demo p1 "<body><p style=""font-family:Arial,Cascadia"">MyText</p></body>" p3
```

this produces the following output for param2 where the double quotes are not changed at all:

> `"'<body><p style=""font-family:Arial,Cascadia"">MyText</p></body>'"`

### The ugly workaround

I managed to get the desired output by replacing from "" to " like so:

```
set x=%2
echo '%x:""="%'
```

**I wonder if this is the recommended way or if there is an easier way**. I read a lot on this subject
with https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php and http://www.windowsinspired.com/understanding-the-command-line-string-and-arguments-received-by-a-windows-program/ being cited most often but unfortunately neither did help.

Comment: Windows command processor `cmd.exe` interprets only `"` as argument string delimiter as explained by its help output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window. It is not possible to escape `"` with a backslash or any other character to be interpreted as literal character inside an argument string. However, in all versions of the HTML specification is clearly written that either `"` or `'` can be used for an attribute value. So the simple solution is using `demo p1 "<body><p style='font-family:Arial,Cascadia'>MyText</p></body>"` as this is 100% valid HTML.

Comment: It is of course also possible to use `demo p1 "<body><p style='font-family:Arial,Cascadia'>MyText</p></body>"` and use in batch file `set "x=%~2"` and `set "x=%x:'="%"` to pass the HTML code with `'` around the `style` attribute value and replace both with `"` inside the batch file although not necessary according to HTML specification.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Mofi. I corrected the family-issue and I think your suggestion to switch from " to ' is what will really help me in the long run :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, only double quotes can be used to escape a full argument, but the quotes itself can't be escaped inside an argument.
If you still insist on using double quotes in your arguments, the double double quote seems to be one of the best solutions.

But to get and handle the arguments in a safe way, you should switch to delayed expansion, because delayed expanded content isn't parsed anymore (contrary to percent expansion).

```
set "arg1=%~1"
set "arg2=%~2"
..
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "arg1=!arg1:""="!"
set "arg2=!arg2:""="!"
echo !arg1! !arg2!
```